# Is there a way to stop flickering on 7-segment when counting up/down by multiplexing?

Tags: c

Board: Using EasyPIC v7
MCU: PIC16F874

I recently started to try out some code and working on some microchips for counting up and down as well as reset, on 3 7-segment displays. So far I have gotten down the basics, i just lack some optimization and some problem fixing. You can see a hint of C# style in the code xD.

My main issue is that whenever i count up or count down, the segment display that is updating flickers, i know why its happening i just want to know where i can use the "Delay_ms()" where it would slow down the update rate without interrupting the multiplexing.

```
/*
   a1 is for ones, a10 is for tens, and a100 for hundreds

   char nums1 and nums2 are the binary codes for the 7-segment.
   I was testing out wether to use 0 in the beginning or at the end.

*/

static int a1; static int a10; static int a100;
char nums1 [10] = {0b00000110, 0b01011011, 0b01001111, 0b01100110, 0b01101101, 0b01111101, 0b00000111, 0b01111111, 0b01101111, 0b00111111};
char nums2 [10] = {0b00111111, 0b00000110, 0b01011011, 0b01001111, 0b01100110, 0b01101101, 0b01111101, 0b00000111, 0b01111111, 0b01101111};


static int initMain()
{
   a1 = 1; a10 = 1; a100 = 1;
}
void main()
{
   initMain();
   ADCON1 = 0x0F;
   TRISA = 0;
   TRISB = 0xFF;
   TRISD = 0;
   do
   {
      if (PORTB.B0)            // Here is where the problem lies i guess
      {
        Delay_ms(100);         
        a1 = a1 + 2;           // Counting up by 2
      }
      if (PORTB.B1)            
      {
        Delay_ms(100);
        a1 = a1 - 2;           // Counting down by 2
      }
      if (PORTB.B2)
      {
        initMain();            // Reset
      }

      PORTA = 1;
      PORTD = nums2[a1-1];
      Delay_ms(5);

      PORTA = 10;
      PORTD = nums2[a10-1];
      Delay_ms(5);

      PORTA = 100;
      PORTD = nums2[a100-1];
      Delay_ms(5);

      if (a1 < 1)
      { a1 = 9; a10--;}

      if (a1 > 10)
      { a1 = 1; a10++;}

      if (a10 > 10)
      { a10 = 1; a100++;}

      if (a10 < 1)
      { a10 = 10; a100--;}

   } while(1);
}
```

Comment: Only update the display output when the value has changed. But perhaps you are indexing the segment value arrays out of range, since the range check is applied to the index *after* you update. The range check should be immediately after the increment or decrement.

Comment: If i update the display output when the value has changed wouldnt it only show me the screen when pressing the button? Anyways i have found a fix after scratching my head a little more, i added a "time" int variable witch gets up to 10 and resets to zero everytime the do{} loops, so now the if only accepts input when
PORTB.B0 && time == 10

Works fine and pretty easy to change the value of!

Comment: Isn't that what you want? You press a button (although the input source wasn't mentioned) and the display changes. Or do the outputs need to be constantly refreshed (as some do)?

Comment: Yes thats the concept of multiplexing on a 7 segment if im correct, where both the displays update with different values with a delay which makes the illuison that both are on at the same time.

Comment: Suppose `a1` is 8. You increment it by 2, now it is 10, and that index is out of range, but you index an array with it, and only later did you check the range.

Comment: But I am changing the output to nums2[a1-1] so when a1 is 10,  it will print the index of a1 - 1 which is 10 - 1 = 9 which is still in range.

Comment: And what about `a1 = a1 - 2`?

Comment: Again i have a condition in the bottom. When a1 < 1 it will make a1 = 10 to restart at 0.

Comment: That is *after* you accessed `nums2[a1-1]`.And in the first case, sorry `a1` is even, so `9` was incremented to `11`, and `10` is out of range. This is not hard to understand.

Comment: So it would give a blank output? I was kinda experiencing probelms when counting down where when it got to example: at 10 counting down it would go down to 9 and then continue going down 2 by 2 i guess you are right there

Comment: So i should move up the If statements?

Comment: The behaviour is *undefined*. Also, if the output needs constant refresh, you aren't doing that in the 100ms delay after pressing a button.

Comment: Of course you should. Increment, check the range. Decrement, check the range.

Comment: All right thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the index ranges, that should be checked according to comments, you should have a display refresh function that is called w/o any delays. The best way to do that is using a timer.
For example: Let the timer set a flag every 100ms or so.
Your main loop can than look like this.

```
int TimerFlag = 0;

main()
{

 init();
 initTimer();

  do{
      if(TimerFlag){
          TimerFlag = 0;
          incrementCounter();
      }
      refreshDisplay();
  } while(1);

}

/////////////////////////////

void timerInterrupt()
{
  TimerFlag = 1;
}
```

With this pattern, the display is updated on every loop but the counter is incremented every 100ms (or the timer interval set by you).
Don't forget to enable the timer interrupt...